# How can I tell if I have the Team Fortress 2 update that supports Snow Leopard 10.6.4?

Tags: team-fortress-2, macos

I recently saw that TF2 has updated its code so it doesn't run slow for the Mac OS X 10.6.4 update (which I was holding off on doing since I wanted to play TF2).

I just saw that I need to restart Steam because of an update which included this:

> OSX: Fix several memory leaks
>   OSX: Fix copy/paste resulting in extra random string data

Sorry for the confusion on the real question. The question I am asking is: Do I have to do/download anything to see if the so called TF2 update for 10.6.4 is on my machine? They have told us before that we shouldn't upgrade to 10.6.4 yet since it was buggy with TF2 (graphics problem) so now that they have advertised it and I have upgraded to 10.6.4, is the update already on my machine or not? I checked the Steam update log as mentioned in one of the answers, but I haven't seen any trace of their 10.6.4 fix.

Another edit:
Apple finally released an update for portal and tf2 specifically. Here's a screenie:

[image: Apple update for TF2, Portal and Starcraft 2]

Comment: Hi! It's very difficult to tell what you're asking in this question because you have asked many questions in sequence. Your question could be "Does this update exist?" or "How do I obtain this update?" or "Am I good?". It would help if you narrowed this down to one specific question, preferably expressed clearly in the title.

Comment: I can tell you in about half an hour.  Just redownloading TF2 (cos I changed hard disks).

Comment: sorry for the temporary edit.  Just realised you were asking about update to TF2 not the update to OSX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty sure by default you don't need to do anything special.

TF2 is set, via steam, to auto-update when an update is available. You can turn this off, however, at which point the game will run, but you will be unable to join any servers running on newer versions.

Similarly, if you update before servers do, you wont be able to join them, however this is rarely the case unless you catch an update *right* as it happens.

TF2 updates do not generally require a steam restart, nor any other individual game for that matter. Steam platform updates, however, may require a restart and generally encompass a much broader spectrum of updates (like the Source engine). It may affect TF2, but again this is automated.

Edit:

With the additional edits to the original question, I'm not sure that my initial response sufficiently answers the question. I would reference Powerlord's answer and say that when in doubt, check the official forums for patch notes, updates, and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

What link are you looking for?

[The update changelog](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4210/)?

Some other evidence of the change?

(Side note: steampowered.com is blocked from where I work, so I assume this is the right update)